# Why my celery task is not running?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I'm following this guide:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

My proj.celery file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'hc.settings')

app = Celery('hc')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task
def debug_task(a):
    print a
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    # Executes every Monday morning at 7:30 a.m.
    'debug-every-minute': {
        'task': 'tasks.debug_task',
        'schedule': crontab(),
        'args': ("BLa BLA BlA", ),
    },
}
```

also, I've added periodic task into /admin/django_celery_beat/

I understand that it's makes not sense to use both `app.conf.beat_schedule` and periodic_task in admin but I don't see expecting entries after

```
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

(I expect that Bla bla will be written under that) Where I'm wrong?

Comment: You will not see any print statements on the console of your django application because the celery task will be run in another process. If you started celery with `celery -A proj worker -l info` in a shell you will see the output there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run celery by

```
celery -A hc worker -B -l info
```

Comment: which stands for `celery --app hc worker --beat --loglevel=INFO`

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the command `python manage.py celery beat` to start your periodic task and see the results. Only you can see the print statement results of celery task in your celery shell rather than the normal Django runserver shell.

Comment: ./manage.py celery beat
Unknown command: 'celery'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
'django_celery_beat',
    'django_celery_results',
    'celery', are in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: This only works with [django-celery](https://github.com/celery/django-celery) installed which is not mandatory.

Comment: use `celery -A hc beat -l info`